# Run program with arbitrary filename in emacs

Tags: file, emacs

I want to launch an arbitrary program that takes selected filename argument from a buffer that lists files in a directory.

I tried to use `F3` key to insert the filename but the following records a new macro instead which is rather confusing.

```
(define-key minibuffer-local-map [f3] (lambda () (interactive (find-file-at-point))))
```

Comment: The `minibuffer-local-map` is used for certain circumstances when the user is inside the mini-buffer.  Are you in the mini-buffer when you press F3?  (If so, what interactive function did you initiate to get you inside the mini-buffer?)  If not, where are you?  In the main buffer?  Any particular major-mode?  Do you want a global assignment using the `global-map`?  Do you want a buffer-local assignment?  Do you want to add the new key binding only to a specific major mode?

Comment: Any solution that allows me to see filename path will help.

Comment: Your code mistakenly tries to invoke `find-file-at-point` *inside* the `interactive` declaration. Don't do that. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're problem is not completely clear to me, but maybe this helps.

Please see the following screenshot of my Emacs in the *scratch* buffer.  It contains a function and the keybinding, the echo area at the bottom is showing the results from the call to `message`

[image]

For your convenience, here is the function and the keybinding repeated for better copying:

```
(defun command-on-file-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((f (ffap-file-at-point)))
    (message "File is %s" f)))

(global-set-key [f3] 'command-on-file-at-point)
```

Hope, that helps.

Comment: (global-set-key [f3] (lambda () (interactive) (let ((f (ffap-file-at-point))) (start-process "test" "output" "mpv" f))))